# aws-xray captureAWS annotations

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I've begun using AWSXRay in order to get more insight into why performance is not ideal in my lambda function. This lambda function runs a gql service meaning it has lots of outbound requests to other lambda functions as well as dynamodb for caching.

I've added tracing to all aws-sdk client calls by utilizing the following in my handler. It mutates the imported AWS module so that all subsequent usage of AWS clients successful includes aws-xray tracing, regardless of what module imports it. Awesome!

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk';
AWSXRay.captureAWS(AWS);
```

Heres an example of the output:
[image]

## The Problem

The problem is that none of the "Traces" have any annotation regarding the parameters of the requests. Both the annotation and metadata of each trace is empty:
[image]

## The Hope

The hope is that there is a way to configure the AWSXRay CaptureAWS modifications so that they include the arguments of each aws-client request in the annotations or metadata.

## The Question

Is it possible to request that `AWSXRay.captureAWS(AWS);` includes the parameters passed to the aws sdk client invocations in either the annotations or the metadata of the traces it produces?

Answer (score 4):

The resources section contains high level arguments for some clients e.g. DynamoDB table name. Not all arguments are captured by default. This is because they may contain information that the users do not wish to track in their trace and may also be verbose.

For now opt-in is not available in X-Ray SDK for arbitrary API parameters. As a workaround for now, I would suggest that you wrap your sdk calls in a local subsegment and record the parameters you want to capture as annotations or Metadata for that subsegment. Let me know if you need any help in locating docs that allow you to create your own subsegments.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Do you know if that opt-in functionality is planned on being added to the sdk?

Comment: Thanks, I have recorded it as a feature request internally within AWS X-Ray.